# Error while trying build on windows roll a ball learn project

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I follow the roll a ball learn project but when I want to build the game have got errors. Here the message :

> Exception: C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.9f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe
> did not run properly! UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram
> (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args,
> System.String workingDirectory,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe,
> System.String args, System.String workingDirectory,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser,
> System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at <d3ff43e972b043d1b3f49905ec5da738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at <d3ff43e972b043d1b3f49905ec5da738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (UnityEditor.Il2Cpp.Il2CppBuildPipelineData data, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at <d3ff43e972b043d1b3f49905ec5da738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at <d3ff43e972b043d1b3f49905ec5da738>:0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile,
> UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at
> :0)
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at
> :0)
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
> :0) Rethrow as BuildFailedException:
> Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
> (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args,
> UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess
> (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
> target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName,
> System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height,
> UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
> usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at
> :0)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

and

> Failed running C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.9f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe
> --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="WindowsDesktop" --architecture="x64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="K:\Arnaud\Documents\Unity\Project\roll-ball\Temp/StagingArea/Data\Native\GameAssembly.dll"
> --cachedirectory="K:\Arnaud\Documents\Unity\Project\roll-ball\Assets..\Library/il2cpp_cache"
> --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.9f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe"
> --directory=K:/Arnaud/Documents/Unity/Project/roll-ball/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed
> --generatedcppdir=K:/Arnaud/Documents/Unity/Project/roll-ball/Temp/StagingArea/Data/il2cppOutput

My build target is windows x86_x64.
I try to build my project in a folder named Builds at the same root level of assets, packages, etc... like in the learn project (I try to change the folder location and nothing change).
I follow perfectly the project and I have install IL2CPP, restart my computer and lauch vs 2019.
Can you help me ? thanks.

PS : I'm new to unity and that's my first project

Comment: Please show us the errors before. The ones you show us here just say **that** there were errors during the build process but there is no information **what** exactly went wrong. There should be some compiler errors further up in the console -> please post these instead.

Comment: @derHugo I update my question

Comment: In your VisualStudio installation did you tick the modules for `Game Development with C++` and `Desktop Development with C++`?

Comment: @derHugo `Desktop Development with C++` was missing and it's building now ! thanks !

Comment: Glad to help :)